# Can't upload image to Google Ads campaign "Can’t upload this file right now. Try again later."

Tags: google-mobile-ads

Whenever I try to upload an image to Google Ads (app campaign) I'm getting:

> Can’t upload this file right now. Try again later.

[image]

I have waited several hours and tried again, but it still not working. My images stand for the requirements.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to disable your adblocker.
I found the answer here :
https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/146564851/can-t-upload-image-to-google-ads-campaign-can%E2%80%99t-upload-this-file-right-now-try-again-later

Comment: It worked! How did you figure this out?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I saw the solution in another forum

Comment: Can you please refer to that forum? I was struggling to find an answer to this case. Wondering what keywords I had to use, want to learn for my next searching

Comment: The post didn't existed yet when you created the stackoverflow question.

Comment: this is crazy...